# How to bind whole page to BindingContext?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my application I have a situation where I want to display some object on page and then change this object for different one.

So, let's consider I have **MainPage.xaml.cs** like this:

```
...
public Foo Item { get; set; }
public bool SomeCheck {
    get {
        return Item.Bar != "";
    }
}

public MainPage() {
    InitializeComponent();
    SetItem();
    BindingContext = this;
}

private void SetItem() {
    Item = DifferentClass.GetNewItem();
}

private void Next_Clicked(object sender, EventArds e){
    SetItem();
}
...
```

and **MainPage.xaml** like this:

```
...
<Label Text="{Binding Item.Bar}" IsVisible="{Binding SomeCheck}" />
<Button Text="Next" Clicked="Next_Clicked" />
...
```

So I want to bind whole page to BindingContext, to achieve this I've set `BindingContext = this;`. Behaviour which I want is to show `Bar` property of different objects returned by `GetNewItem()` and what I get is frozen page. In debugger Item is changing, but on page I have always value which I've set at the first call.

So the **question** is: can I somehow update `BindingContext` to show what I want? I tried calling `OnPropertyChanged()` but it doesn't work for me.

I know I can set up whole object like

```
BindingContext = { Bar = Item.Bar, SomeCheck = Item.Bar != "" };
```

and the it works, but of course my real scenario is more complex so I don't want to go this way.

Comment: What ever is being used as the backing view model needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the properties in question need to raise the event when changed. Otherwise you will have to manually raise the property changed events for the ones you want reflected in the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OnPropertyChanged`:

XAML:

```
<Label Text="IsVisible" IsVisible="{Binding MyIsVisible}" />
```

In the viewmodel, in your case in `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
private bool myIsVisible = true;

public bool MyIsVisible
{ 
  get => myIsVisible; 
  set
  {
    myIsVisible = value; 
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyIsVisible));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not exact answer for my question, however I think there is no such answer. I've missed that in `OnPropertyChanged` we have to pass name as well.